# Google reCaptcha in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: input, modal-dialog, focus, recaptcha

I use google reCaptcha v2 version in my project. I need to use this reCaptcha in modal. I use bootstrap modal. My problem is this:
when I click on reCaptcha in the modal, it focuses on an input in the modal. I don't want this to happen because when it focuses on the input, the position of the reCaptcha component can be wrong.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
async defer> </script>
            
<script>
var onloadCallback = function() {
            grecaptcha.render("demo", {sitekey: "6LcgSAMTAAAAACc2C7rc6HB9ZmEX4SyB0bbAJvTG", theme: "light"});
      };

</script>


<button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target="#applyModalDOM"
    >
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="applyModalDOM"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="submitModalTitle">Modal title</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" name="deneme" required />
            <div class="g-recaptcha" id="demo"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

what do you think is the reason for this? this is jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/ErkanKabil/bgr8fLzo/5/